# Most Active Contributors Quarterly Report - 1st Quarter 2018

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the second Quarterly edition of the Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

While similar to the monthly report, this report differs in that it contains fewer sections but lists the top 10 users (instead of 5) in each of those sections.

This report will be published after each calendar year quarter. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for 1st Quarter 2018

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Quarterly Reputation Leader Board
3. Quarterly Most Active Editors Award
4. Quarterly Most Active Voters Award
5. Quarterly Most Close Votes Reviewed Award
6. Quarterly Most First Posts Reviewed Award
7. Quarterly Most Late Answers Reviewed Award
8. Quarterly Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award
9. Quarterly Most Reopen Reviews Award
10. Quarterly Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Ranked 1st Summary List
12. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                    SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    1,015
2   grgarside                  825
3   JMY1000                    470
4   patrix                     410
5   Monomeeth                  250
6   Nimesh Neema               230
7   bmike                      220
8   Klanomath                  160
9   pjc90                      150
10  Mark                        90
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 2,550.

---

[image: TITLE: QUARTERLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]

A total of 2,743 users earned reputation during the quarter. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/quarter/apple/2018-01-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   grgarside                245
2   klanomath                209
3   Nimesh Neema             158
4   Allan                    151
5   bmike                    126
6   patrix, IconDaemon        98
7   Monomeeth                 52
8   David Anderson            41
9   user3439894               38
10  ProGrammer                33
```

A big thank you to all 39 users who edited questions or answers this quarter!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  5,022
2   Monomeeth               1,694
3   bro                       531
4   Melvin Jefferson          496
5   LangLangC                 467
6   grgarside                 411
7   bmike                     367
8   Nimesh Neema              290
9   user3439894               224
10  Andre                     174
```

A big thank you to all 229 users who voted on questions or answers this quarter!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1. Note: Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST CLOSE VOTES REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    191
2   patrix                   173
3   Mark                     143
4   JMY1000                  131
5   grgarside                113
6   pjc90                    105
7   fsb                       89
8   Scot                      80
9   IconDaemon                68
10  Monomeeth                 52
```

A big thank you to all 87 users who reviewed Close Votes this quarter!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST FIRST POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   patrix                   376
2   JMY1000                  358
3   grgarside                312
4   Allan                    286
5   Scot                     274
6   fsb                      264
7   pjc90                    222
8   Melvin Jefferson         146
9   Monomeeth                127
10  Jawa                     110
```

A big thank you to all 64 users who reviewed First Posts this quarter!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LATE ANSWERS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    231
2   LangLangC                175
3   Glorfindel               133
4   JMY1000                  103
5   Scot                      90
6   grgarside                 76
7   pjc90                     61
8   fsb                       40
9   Jawa                      30
10  IconDaemon                29
```

A big thank you to all 46 users who reviewed Late Answers this quarter!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LOW-QUALITY POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    151
2   JMY1000                   90
3   Scot                      66
4   Tetsujin                  59
5   Mark                      55
6   pjc90                     46
7   grgarside                 44
9   IconDaemon                38
10  fsb                       36
```

A big thank you to all 34 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this quarter!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST REOPEN POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    44
2   patrix                   41
3   JMY1000                  31
4   fsb                      20   
5   Tetsujin                 18
6   IconDaemon               17
7   Mark                     16
8   pjc90                    14
9   grgarside                10
10  Scot                      9
```

A big thank you to all 23 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this quarter!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST SUGGESTED EDITS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                   211
2   grgarside               111
3   Scot                    108
4   Glorfindel               89
5   patrix                   65
6   techraf                  63
7   JMY1000                  54
8   Monomeeth                49
9   fsb                      42
10  pjc90                    41
```

A big thank you to all 108 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this quarter!

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Close Votes Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**6.    Most First Posts Reviewed Award**

- [patrix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/patrix)

**7.    Most Late Answers Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**8.    Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Reopen Reviews Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In the 1st Quarter of 2018 our [Moderators](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 1,363 flags with an average handling time of 14 minutes. In summary, we:

- deleted 549 comments
- deleted 839 posts
- closed 584 posts
- edited 578 posts
- created 305 posts
- created 1,117 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)